# Creating and persisting DbContext schema without migrations

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm

I am looking for a way, **how to generate and persist DB schema without having migrations inbetween**?

So to speak, directly modifying the database with no tools inbetween.

I want something along the lines of: `SetSchema<DbContext>(myUserContext)` and so that it automatically goes through the context data, generates the SQL and executes. Also, the inverse of `UnsetSchema<DbContext>(myUserContext)`.

I need this for an Installer system I have here. Instead of migrations, I just want to make the required tables and schema given a context. I don't need steps between. In other words... on installation I set the tables up, on uninstallation I unset the tables.

I have been looking through EF6.1.2 sources. I've found `Migration.Builders` which seem to be relevant, but cannot seem to find a way how to use them. I have been reverse engineering the path through the API, but I stumbled once I hit the `MigrationOperations` that are generated through `EdmModelDiffer.Diff`. Apparently, the `EdmModelDiffer` is internal.

Comment: Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges - You can then run migrations from the command line... migrate.exe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Comment: I know, but I am looking to do it from inside the `*.exe` itself. I am running the software on Mono, and there are problems running the default tools.

Comment: Look at the code in migrate.exe, it is Open Source...

Comment: @ErikEJ as I already mentioned in the Q, I want to avoid migrations. `migrate.exe` works by utilising the embedded `DbMigration` classes which I have to generate beforehand. I am looking to do this with no migrations at all.

Comment: No can do (with EF, anyway)